# how to call php function in onchange method in html?

Tags: php

i am new to PHP(i am working on android). My page contains one table,that is changing according to the database changes.My Table contains drag down options,if i change any thing in drag down options,we have to enter these into datebase.I am calling script function "updatePrepStatus()".It is not working,Pls help me.

```
 <script >
     function updatePrepStatus(itemName) {    

       alert(itemName);
       <?php
                    echo " updatePrepStatus-- ";
          ?> ;  

     }      
</script>

<?php

                         //$Order_no=$_GET['OrderId'];
                         $result =  mysql_query("select Menu_Item_Name, Menu_Item_quantity,Menu_Item_Price,PreparationStatus from order_details where order_id='$Order_no' && status!='C' ");
                         $rows_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

                         $i=0;
                         $ItemName="";
                         while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result) )
                         {
                            if($i==0)
                            {
                                echo "<table id='table1' style='WIDTH: 400px;' border='3' cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=3 width=693 align=center>
                                    <tbody>";
                                echo "<tr><td><font color='#0000e' size='2'><strong>Item
                                    Name</strong></font></td>
                                  <td><font color='#0000e'
                                    size=2><strong>Quantity</strong></font></td>
                                  <td><font color='#0000e'
                                    size=2><strong>Price</strong></font></td>
                                  <td><font color='#0000e'
                                    size=2><strong>Status</strong></font></td></tr>";
                            }
                            if($row['PreparationStatus']=='NEW')
                                $ps2='READY';
                            else
                                $ps2='NEW';
                            $ItemName=$row['Menu_Item_Name'];
                            echo $ItemName;
                            echo"<tr>
                              <td><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['Menu_Item_Name']."</font></td>
                              <td><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['Menu_Item_quantity']."</font></td>
                              <td><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['Menu_Item_Price']."</font></td>
                              <td><SELECT NAME='Select[]' id='PrepStatus' onChange=updatePrepStatus($ItemName)><OPTION VALUE='NEW'><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['PreparationStatus']."
                                                       </OPTION><OPTION VALUE='READY'><font color='#0000e' size='2'>$ps2</OPTION></SELECT>&nbsp;</font></td></tr>";
                            $i++;
                         }
                         if($i==0)
                         {
                             echo "<p align='center'>NO RECORDS<strong><font color='white' size='3'>";
                         } 
                         else
                         {
                                echo "</tbody></table></p>
                                  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p>
                                  <p>
                                  <p></p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                  <input value='Submit' type='submit' name='submit'>";  
                         }
                     ?>
```

pls help me.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between *server-side PHP* and *client-side Javascript*?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams there are no more kittens left already?

Comment: @suresh Also, please clean your html, that plethora of &nbsp; and the font attribute look messy..use CSS instead!

Comment: Just in case the asker didn't know; 1 - PHP is executed on the server *before* the page loads. 2 - Javascript is run *after* the page loads.

Comment: @Damien: Kittens still have their old death trigger. And I'm not quite sure this type of question would count as that...

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you're confusing PHP (which runs on the computer that's serving as a web server) with javascript (which runs in the browser the visitor to the site is running).  They can't interact directly.

They can, however, interact using a mechanism commonly known as AJAX.  This requires you to write a server side script that will take requests and send responses, and a client side javascript that sends requests and processes responses from the server.

Quick example using PHP and jQuery:

If you write a server script and install it at http://www.exampler.com/ajaxserver.php:

```
<?php

echo (json_encode (array (
    'response' => $_GET ['message'], 
    'luckynumber' => mt_rand ())));
?>
```

On the client side:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/ajaxserver.php',
    datatype: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello, this is the message that will be returned by AJAX!'
    },
    success: functioon (data, status, xhr)
    {
        alert (data.response);
        alert ('Your lucky number is: ' + data.luckynumber);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the distinction between *server-side* code, such as PHP, and *client-side* code, ie Javascript.

It is not possible to call a PHP function from your Javascript.  You *could*, if you want, use an AJAX call to call your server in response to a Javascript event, and that AJAX call could be fed into a new PHP page which you would have to create specially.  However, it's not clear that you need something like this, as it is a bit difficult to determine what you were trying to do - if it's not something that requires a new call to the server, then you don't need this.

I would recommend that you need to know a little more about web development in order to understand the disctintion between client-side and server-side code, so that you properly understand why this won't work, at this point.  We could recommend any number of complicated solutions where we give you a lot of code, but you need to understand why something does or doesn't work according to how web applications work.

[Here's one article](http://www.virtualshowrooms.co.za/articlepage.php?cp=101) and [another](http://tinsology.net/2009/06/client-side-vs-server-side-code/) just to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'db_config.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM Category ORDER BY c_id ASC";

// Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());?>
<select id='cat' name='cat' class='input2' onselect="function myfunction()"> <option value='Select '>Select Category</option>;

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['c_id']}'>{$row['c_name']}</option>";

}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;


?>
```

Comment: it does not seem it works 
you cannot call a php function on 'onselect' , as onselect is for javascript or jquery , as i know.